# Putting something on top of a modal (Zurb Foundation)

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I want a div to appear on top of a Zurb Foundation reveal modal.

However, my div refuses to be shown on top of the modal.

The z-index of the modal is 1006. When I set my on-top div to 1010, or even 99999, it still sits underneath the modal.

The only way I can get it to work is by setting the foundation modal's `.reveal-overlay`'s z-index to 0 (even 1 puts it on top of my div), but that messes up other elements.

How can I put an element on top of a Zurb Foundation modal?

Comment: Hard for anyone to help without a [mcve] that reproduces the issue

Answer (score 1):

Your `div` needs to on the top level of the dom for this to work.

The following will work.

```
<div class="reveal">
<h1>my reveal</h1>
</div>

<div style="z-index: 1100; width:500px; height: 500px; 
top: 100px; position: absolute;left: 200px;">On top of the reveal</div>

</body>
</html>
```