# Foundation 6 Nested Modal, Z-index issue

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am trying to place the cross button on the top right corner as displayed in the image;[image: Close Modal not displayed properly] the Z-index is not working for the nested modal.. It is a layer of Z-Index that has been used, .reveal-overlay with position: fixed and Z-index value of 1005, inside which .reveal with z-index 1006 and I want to have close-modal on top of everything. - Code -

HTML -

```
<div class="reveal-overlay">
   <div class="reveal">
      <div class="close-modal">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.reveal-overlay {
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1005;
}
.reveal {
   position: relation;
   z-index: 1006;
}
```

If I give position: absolute to close-modal and z-index: 1007, it does not come on top, any suggestion that why is this happening or the mistake that I am doing in fixing this? 
I have read these stack-overflow links for references -
 1. [CSS I want a div to be on top of everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421775/css-i-want-a-div-to-be-on-top-of-everything)
 2. [CSS z-index not working (position absolute)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971340/css-z-index-not-working-position-absolute)
 3. [Putting something on top of a modal (Zurb Foundation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847267/putting-something-on-top-of-a-modal-zurb-foundation)
 4. https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

The link for code pen is - 
https://codepen.io/IamManchanda/pen/PmaxBz

In this, the cross in the top right corner is to be placed outside the white box. Thanks to anyone who helps me with this problem.

Comment: this is an overflow issue not z-index issue ... you need to make sure `reveal` has overflow set to visible

Comment: Yes, it worked with overflow visible for reveal, thank you @TemaniAfif